# Publishing to web overwrites the XML resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, publish

I have an asp MVC website in which I have built an XML with all the strings. This acts as my resources file.

I have built it so that someone who doesn't know how to code can come to my website and edit it.

Everything works fine with the editing and all but the problem arises when I try to republish my website. The XML gets overwritten by an older version that I have locally.

How do I over come this?

Note: I've used this http://afana.me/2013/11/default.aspx to achieve the xml resources.

Comment: How is the resource file modified runtime from your users?

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you want to exclude that file from publishing, [this article should help](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment)